# The system cannot log you on now because the domain is not available

Tags: ldap, samba, ubuntu-12.04, domain-controller

I am using two virtualbox machines, one running XUbuntu 12.4 LTs and the other running a Windows XP as a testbed for implementing a Samba-based domain. The Linux machine is my PDC and the XP machine is the client. Samba uses LDAP as a backend.

The installation is almost successful and I managed to join my XP machine to the domain. Nevertheless when I try to log in using an existing user, I receive the following error:

```
The system cannot log you on now because the domain is not available
```

As I said before, the server and the client are both running on two virtualbox machines. After the installtion of my server and joining the network, I put both machines to Internal Networking mode and I can ping each machine from the other.

Samba version is 3.6.3

Does anyone have any idea what might be the problem? Do I need a gateway or DNS address? I am totally running out of ideas :((

Comment: For a Samba question, this needs much more information to be able to get a definitive answer

Answer (score 1):

One minute of searching I found " in SAMBA HOWTO section 3.5.5. The problem was that one has to create users (local & smb ) and machine trust account after installation and configuring SAMBA server not before it. Otherwise samba would consider them as local system account. "

Otherwise you can try: Run wireshark and see what packets are being dropped between the two machines.  Perhaps a port is blocked (netbios)?  Are the clocks on the two machines in sync?  What IP addresses do the two computers have?  IS there a firewall/iptables running on the PDC?

Comment: Thank you for the reponse but I have well cretaed the users and machine trust accounts after installation and configuration of my SAMBA server. I again verified this using pbedit command.

Comment: In addition I have already successfully joined the domain but in the login screen it can't contact the domain.